# Converting NGINX to apache rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

Currently I am doing a project setup in my local(Apache) whichi is in NGINX.

I am facing trouble in converting the rules from NGINX to .htaccess rules.
Can some one help me out in converting the following rule to .htaccess rule.

```
location /test/ {
        set $store_code test;
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler_test;
        expires 30d;
    }
```

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ServerFault! Did you find this document? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html Please try that first, and if you run into issues please update your question on what kind of issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I have gone through the document but that rewrite rule is quite different than this rule. and there it is suggesting how to convert from .htaccess rule to NGINX rule. I am quite new to these so  can some one help me out to convert from NGINX rule to .htaccess.

Comment: It's not really possible, because this depends on other parts of the `server` block which are not shown here.